Find residue for $\frac{1}{z^3-z^5}$
Find residue for $\frac{1}{z^3-z^5}$ at all isolated singularities.
We know that the singularities occur at $z=0, \pm 1$. Now, we try to obtain the Laurent series about $z=0$:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{z^3-z^5} = \frac{1}{(z^4+z^3)(1-z)} &= \frac{1}{z^4+z^3} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n \\
\frac{1}{z^4+z^3} [1+z+z^2+z^3 + \dots]
\end{split}
\end{align}
But the $\frac{1}{z^4+z^3}$ prevents us from seeing this in such a way that reveals the residue. So we observe that $\frac{1}{z^4+z^3} = \frac{1}{z^3(z+1)}$. Would a partial fraction decomposition be most beneficial here - to eventually rewrite all this in such a way so that the residue is apparent?

$$\frac{1}{z^3-z^5}=\frac{1}{z^3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-z^2}=\frac{1}{z^3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2n}.$$

@Riemann This is great, thank you. What would be some steps to take to find Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z^3-z^5}$ about $z= \pm 1$?

The computation of the residue at $0$ is easy, as you were shown in the comments. You just use the fact that$$\frac1{z^3-z^5}=\frac1{z^3}\cdot\frac1{1-z^2}=\frac1{z^3}+\frac1z+z+z^3+z^5+\cdots$$At the points $\pm1$, you can use the formula$$\operatorname{res}_a\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)},$$which holds when $f$ and $g$ are analytic, defined on a neighborhood of $a$, and $g'(a)\ne0$. So$$\operatorname{res}_{\pm1}\frac1{z^3-z^5}=\frac1{3\times(\pm1)^2-5\times(\pm1)^4}=-\frac12.$$

Brilliant solution! What is the name of the formula $\mathrm{res}_a \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$? I'm interested in learning more about it

I am not aware of any name for that formula. It is an easy consequence of the fact that, when the limit $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)h(z)$ exists, then the residue of $h$ at $a$ is that limit.
